# Multi Line Text box for External Content Types

Tags: list

I have an External Content Type mapped to SQL Server External Data. There is a column with more than 350 Characters. So, I made that column with Datatype of NVarchar with 350 size. I have created a new SharePoint list by using this External Content type. But in the SharePoint the list is showing only single line instead of Multiple lines. How do I fix this issue? I will need to show all 350 Characters in SharePoint.

Comment: Try using "text" type in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks Arsalan. Thats fixed now. It is working with the "Text" type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"text"` type in `SQL Server`