# SharePoint external list (sql) with multi lined text field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, bcs, external-content-type

I have an external content type with one of the fields having huge text in it. (SQL type: `varchar(MAX)`).

When I create the external list and open a new form, the field is a single line textbox and it is supposed to be multi-lined, to accept large text.

I have gone through this ([Multi Line Textbox for External Content Types](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158441/multi-line-text-box-for-external-content-types)) post, tried changing the SQL datatype to `Text` But no luck.

Has anyone solved this issue? (**SharePoint 2013 + SQL Server 2014**)

Comment: Experienced this same problem with SQL 2014. the only work around was to use InfoPath